# Widget Settings disable on drop - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So the problem is that when dropping a new widget in the widget area the settings and the fields disappear and by pressing the save button it reappears.

Screenshots Below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFWkk.png)

[CODE OF ONE OF THE WIDGETS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUkHW.jpg)
Actual Code of one of the widgets. Theme name replaced with the word example.

```
    <?php

class example_category_widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_options = array( 'classname' => 'example_category', 'description' => 'Category List' );
        parent::__construct( 'example_category', esc_html__('example - Category', 'textdomain' ), $widget_options );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : 'Category List';
        echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'] . $args['before_content'];

        $string = '<ul class="widget-content">';
        $catlist = get_terms( 'category' );
        if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
            foreach ( $catlist as $key => $item ) {
                $string .= '<li>'. $item->name . '<br />';
                $string .= '<em>'. $item->description . '</em> </li>';
            }
        }
        $string .= '</ul>';

        echo $string;
        wp_reset_query();
        echo $args['after_content'] . $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : 'Category'; ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" /><br/>
        </p><?php
    }
    // Apply settings to the widget instance.
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance[ 'title' ] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
        return $instance;
    }
}
?>
```

**Code of Registering the Sidebar**

```
function example_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar Widgets', 'textdomain' ),
            'id'            => 'primary-sidebar',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'textdomain' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="background-title '.$float.'"><span>',
            'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
            'before_content' => '<div class="widget-content"> ',
            'after_content' => '</div>',
        ) );
}


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'example_widgets_init' );
```

This happening to all the widgets but on changing the theme widgets working fine. What can be the problem? I have tried disabling the admin scripts and the scripts I enqueuing to the admin page.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the actual code, not a screenshot of the code. You're much more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: Okay!  I'm including the code. Thank you!

Comment: seems issues in theme or plugins. just deactivate plugins and check. your code working fine for me.